# How to enable second level imports for my react component library packages?

Tags: reactjs, lerna

I have created my own react component library using lerna and I have a package that holds multiple icons. I want to provide the possibility to use path imports, to avoid pulling in unused modules.

So I want to use

```
import PlusIcon from '@my-lib/icon/plus'
```

instead of

```
import { PlusIcon } from '@my-lib/icon'
```

in my react app, without any additional configuration.

I am struggling to find any documentation/tutorial for this, so I don't even know where to start. I would be grateful for any hint.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi ! Did you find a way?

Answer (score 0):

Your `plus` file need to have an `default export` for the PlusIcon.

For instance

```
function PlusIcon = () => <p>+</p>;

export default PlusIcon;
```

As long as you have something like that, you can import it as

`import PlusIcon from 'path-to-plus-icon`